# "No visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'base64EncodedString" error in MKStoreKit

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to upgrade my MKStoreKit to version 4.0 in my app so I can incorporate the "restore in app purchase" feature into my app. Apple wants to reject my app due to this missing feature. I've been able to solve all of my "ARC" issues so far but I'm stuck with the "No visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'base64EncodedString" error. From what I can tell, this error is related to the server functionality required to let reviewers run your in app purchase without actually purchasing it. I'm uninterested in this feature and would love to know how to bypass it. I've been unable to find out how to do this. Does anyone know how I can disable this?

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using `base64EncodedString` method somewhere, but you have forgotten to include a header with the category declaring it. If you are using [a popular base-64 encoding library for iOS](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64), the header name is `"NSData+Base64.h"`.

Answer (score 0):

First add `NSData+Base64.h` and `NSData+Base64.m` in your project and in the class where you are getting the error import #import `NSData+Base64.h` and you will get out of that error.